# what's the efficient technique to build a crud form using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm just start digging into mvc asp.net stack, I've Been for two days trying to submit a form to action controller I find myself in a very narrow choices, for instance in web form approach we can submit a form with multiple actions and we can use all possible elements to achieve that (buttons, a tag, ...)

**Questions :**

1 - Is asp.net mvc a OneForm-OneAction process ?

2 - How can we implement a CRUD actions in one form ? (according to question 1)

Comment: This: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/crud-operation-in-Asp-Net-mvc-framework/ or maybe this if you use EF: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Thank you for the help @freshbm it's not really what I'm asking for. In a nutshell, I'm trying to use one view for all CRUD actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC is not really designed to enable one view for multiple actions.

To answer your first question, yes, MVC is designed so that each action corresponds to a specific view or partial view. Partial views are an interesting area because using them you can combine the output of multiple actions into one overall view.

In terms of CRUD operations, I would rely initially on the scaffolding features in Visual Studio as they will create fairly decent Controllers, Actions and Views based on your model which will do all the of the CRUD operations via Entity Framework. Right click your project > Add > New Scaffolded Item > MVC 5 controller with views using Entity Framework

Comment: Try it out, it is actually very neat when you get going with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily post data from your view (form is not a must) to your controllers using `jquery-ajax`:

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="button" id="send" value="Save" onclick="SendName()" />

<script>
     function SendName() {
        var name= document.getElementById("name").value;

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/GetName",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({                                     
                  "Name": name,                                     
           }),
           success: function () {
             alert("Ok");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
              }
        });
         return true;
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: what's the utility of using mvc then ? thank you any way

Comment: In this scenario, mvc can handle your server side logic and database interactions. Without mvc or some other server side code, you would have to do all that in JavaScript on the client. In asp.net 5/core 1, mvc and web API are the same thing which makes these kind of scenarios much more flexible compared to asp.bet mvc 4.x where you would need a separate mvc and api controller